# How to test express api on Travis

Tags: node.js, api, testing, express, travis-ci

As mention in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719697/testing-rest-api-built-using-node-jsexpress-on-travis-ci), the following lines only works on local machine for testing.

```
node app.js
karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
```

If I put it into the .travis.yml, it make Travis hanging on the "node app.js" line and fail the test after timeout. I think this is because node is supposed to start the app.js and keep listening. On the local machine, I can open 2 terminal windows and run them separately but I am not sure how to do it on Travis. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node app.js &` will make Travis run app.js in the background (this should also work locally). The "&" bit is a standard piece of shell syntax to make a process run in the background.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!